# Output in powershell struglling

Tags: powershell, output

```
function Get-PCinfo {
    <#
    .Synopsis
        Short description
    .DESCRIPTION
       Long description
    .EXAMPLE
       Example of how to use this cmdlet
    .EXAMPLE
       Another example of how to use this cmdlet
    .NOTES
        <Zadanie 5>
        <Author email>
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        # Param1 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
            Position = 0)]
        [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME

        ## Param2 help description
        #[int]
        #[switch]$outFile = $false
    )

    Begin {
        $Info = @()

        $Info | Format-List
    }

    Process {
        foreach ($computer in $ComputerName) {
            $NotReachableComputers = $null
            Write-Host "Testing connectivity $computer ..... please wait" -ForegroundColor White            
            if (Test-Connection $computer -Quiet -Count 1) {
                Get-CimInstance win32_UserAccount | ForEach-Object {
                    $PCInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
                        ComputerName     = $env:COMPUTERNAME
                        Name             = [string](Get-CimInstance win32_UserAccount).Name
                        SID              = [string](Get-CimInstance win32_UserAccount).SID
                        Lockout          = [string](Get-CimInstance win32_UserAccount).Lockout
                        Disabled         = [string](Get-CimInstance win32_UserAccount).Disabled
                        LocalAdminMember = $_.LocalAdminMember 
                    } 
                }
            }
            else {
                $NotReachableComputers += $computer.name
            }
        }
    }

    End {
        if ($NotReachableComputers -ne $null) {
            Write-Host "This system is not available on network" -ForegroundColor Red
            Write-Host $NotReachableComputers
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "Code worked on all PCs" -ForegroundColor Green
            Write-Output $PCInfo
        }
        #List of systems that were not available on the network
        #List of output from systems that were available
        #List where the output file is located
    }
}
```

Output now:
[image]
Expected output.... every user may be belowe another and the other things same....

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you keep overwriting the value of `$PCInfo` inside the `Process` block, and then at the very end you output whatever value was last assigned.

Remove the assignment to `$PCInfo` completely, and just output the objects immediately once created. You probably also want to explicitly pass `$computer` as the remote computer name for `Get-CimInstance` to query:

```
function Get-PCinfo {
    <#
    .Synopsis
        Short description
    .DESCRIPTION
       Long description
    .EXAMPLE
       Example of how to use this cmdlet
    .EXAMPLE
       Another example of how to use this cmdlet
    .NOTES
        <Zadanie 5>
        <Author email>
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        # Param1 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
            Position = 0)]
        [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME

        ## Param2 help description
        #[int]
        #[switch]$outFile = $false
    )

    Begin {
        $NotReachableComputers = @()
    }

    Process {
        foreach ($computer in $ComputerName) {
            Write-Host "Testing connectivity $computer ..... please wait" -ForegroundColor White
            if (Test-Connection $computer -Quiet -Count 1) {
                Get-CimInstance win32_UserAccount -ComputerName $computer | ForEach-Object {
                    # Don't assign this object to a variable, just let it "bubble up" to the caller
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        ComputerName     = $computer
                        Name             = $_.Name
                        SID              = $_.SID
                        Lockout          = $_.Lockout
                        Disabled         = $_.Disabled
                        LocalAdminMember = $_.LocalAdminMember 
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                # Keep track of unreachable machines still
                $NotReachableComputers += $computer
            }
        }
    }

    End {
        if ($NotReachableComputers.Count -ge 1) {
            Write-Host "This system is not available on network" -ForegroundColor Red
            Write-Host $NotReachableComputers
        }
    }
}
```

To write the accounts to a file, simply pipe the output from your function to `Export-Csv` or similar:

```
Get-PCinfo -ComputerName pc01,pc02,pc03 |Export-Csv path\to\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```